# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('coupons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('expiry_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_DATE'));
        });
    }
```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `coupons` add `expiry_date` date not null default CURRENT_DATE)

Comment: I don't believe MySQL has a `CURRENT_DATE` placeholder. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: yes.only CURRENT_TIMESTAMP placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
$table->date('expiry_date')->default(Carbon::now());
```

Comment: that fix my problem.Thanks

Comment: I don't think this will fix in the current date though.. it will continue using the date as at time of migration. DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') should solve this